# I have two lists one for x values and one for y values, I want to make a list from these

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have two lists one for the x values, and one for the y values. The list for the y -values is constantly being updated (see code). I want to make a graph out of these but I don' t know how.

Thank you for the help.

## Here is the code I already have:

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


yvalues = []
xvalues = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
var = 0
nummer=0
while var < 10 :  # This constructs an infinite loop
   nummer=nummer+1
   yvalues.append(nummer)
   time.sleep(1)
#   print(elements)
   var=var+1


time.sleep(1)

while var==10:
    nummer=nummer+1
    yvalues.append(nummer)
    del yvalues [0]
#    print(elements)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: where you have the comment about the infinite loop it is not infinite. The second `while` loop would be infinite. In order to create the plot, have a look at the [matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html).

Comment: There's too much going on here to figure out what you really want: 1) join two lists into one; 2) plot the (x,y) values -- they don't need to be joined for this, btw; 3) do a real time plot with continuously updated values; 4) ??  It would help if you could just ask one clear question.

Answer (score 1):

To make the list of (x,y) pairs, use the Python **zip** method:

```
point_list = zip(xvalues, yvalues)
```

The documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).  I assume that you can find a plotting routine in the matplotlib documentation -- or in on-line examples -- without actually needing help from us.